# How to submit DetailsView data on pressing enter in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

I found, on simple form in ASP.NET page I can submit its values by pressing enter key by including form fields into Panel control and set up its default button.

But how can I do this for DetailsView? I want to submit by insert button on inserting and update button on updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `DefaultButton property` (Default Submit Button)

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" defaultbutton="Button1">

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

</asp:Panel>
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx

You can also define `AccessKey property`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.accesskey.aspx

Comment: But DetailsWiew has more buttons: Insert on insert mode, Update on update mode. I can imagine do in in code behind, but is not another simplest way? Another story is, I am refactoring application where DetailsView controls are not Buttons but LinkButtons (I have read about some problems using this control as default button)...

Comment: You can use asp:Button, and for your first problem code Behind can also be an alternative solution

Comment: It is not exactly what I was looking for, but you are close. So I select your reply as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Fanda i am happy to help you another day on another subject